# How can I run the Search Activity in a different thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, searchview

I am writing an app that has a searchview widget, and I'm using a searchable.xml configuration and a SearchActivity to search and display results pending on a query from the SearchView widget according to this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html
Everything works fine, however there is some delay between the time the user presses the enter button to search, and the time the SearchActivity is displayed.
I commented out the Search algorithm and left just a textview in the SearchActivity, but the lag was still there. Is it possible to run the SearchActivity in a different thread or something else like that so as to display the SearchActivity only when it is fully initialized?

Comment: So the delay isn't because of your search algorithm?

Comment: Yes, it  isn't. I think the delay might be from hiding the keyboard, because when the keyboard is hidden, there is some kind of background in the area where the keyboard was and when this is cleared, the new activity starts.

Comment: Are u running in a simulator?

Comment: No.. on a physical device.

Comment: Try running on a faster device the keyboard fading is android defined i suppose, and to run your search algo you can use Async Task.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem you can accept so that others can know this is the answer when they are in the same situation

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` is used to do a process that you want to seperate from the UI and display the result in the UI

Refer:

[Async Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: searching and waiting for the result of the async-task will also mean a delay.  because the `get()` method will wait for the task to complete. [see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29)

Comment: Using an Async Task solved the problem but created another one. I need to be able to cancel a running Task instantly and begin a new one if the user decides to do a new search while the previous one hasn't completed. Calling cancel() on Async Task cancels it as soon as possible but not immediately which isn't good enough for me. I ended up using the Executor class.

Comment: Good that you used Executor class. Awesome move. Please do add that as an answer, so that it may help others